# Taking control of video sent to other android app

Tags: android, android-file

I want to send video files to other apps and take full control of it, i.e., I want to send a video file (stored in external storage in phone) in a way so that I can know if the User is watching that video and if he finished the video.?

For now What I have done is: I have sent the path of the video when the other apps ask for it. 
But by doing this I won't know if the user has watched the video fully.

What I want : I want to absolutely know that the user has watched the video in the other app.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to send a video file (stored in external storage in phone) in a way so that I can know if the User is watching that video and if he finished the video

Sorry, that is not possible. What the user does with the video in the other app is up to the user and that other app. The other app might not be a video player, for example. And you cannot spy on the behavior of that other app, for obvious privacy reasons.

If you need that degree of control, play the video back within your own app (e.g., use ExoPlayer).

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare for your quick reply. 

For privacy reasons : I must agree. 

But, then I would like to ask , how does the Google AdMob know when the viewer watched?

Comment: AdMob is a library that is installed into an app, not an external app. For the purposes of access, it's code runs in the current app. The video player is contained within AdMob's library code.

Comment: Ok, So for full control I will have to make a Library. ? Thanks a lot for quick help   @RedBassett

Comment: In theory, yes, you could make a library that manages the playback of that video source, but this would be embedded into someone else's app, not connected to your own app. In theory your library can enforce rules around playback, but it's hosted within another app, so they get to choose how the library is called.

Comment: How the library is called shouldn't be my concern.. right?? But If the other app calls it. I can control the Video like I can control if the video is actually being watched and when it finished.. right?